# Unified application switcher (browser tabs <--> native window)

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, google-chrome, window-manager

I don't like that alt+tab only switches between native windows, and not between browser tabs.

I want to switch between applications with alt+tab, no matter if they are run in a browser tab or in a native window.

Up to now I used [Quick Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-tabs/jnjfeinjfmenlddahdjdmgpbokiacbbb) to switch between browser tabs, but nevertheless it is confusing, since I need to think before switching the application:

> do you want to switch bach to a browser tab, or to a native window.

I was offline for some days, and back at the keyboard I realized that I sometimes use quick-tab to switch back to a native application (which does not work) or I use alt-tab to switch from native application to a browser tab (which does not work, too).

Which window manager could help to get a simplified and unified application switching experience?

Update: Avoiding browser tabs is not a solution for me.

Comment: There is the desktop environment that controls windows, and there is the application that controls tabs. Different realms. One approach could be to configure your browser to open new links in new windows instead of new tabs.

Comment: @vanadium in this context I am user. I don't care for implementation details. Using windows instead of tabs is an ugly work-around (and not a solution). Nevertheless, thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: Not caring for implementation details may not be wise. Sometimes it helps to accept something if you better understand how it works (and why it may not work differently). Note that full screen windows with window task buttons underneat does not really differ from having tabs within a single window.

Comment: @guettli what is it about the solution of forcing webpages to occupy their own windows so they  to appear in the window-switcher that doesn't work for you?

Comment: @pbhj I have a lot of browser tabs, and only few native windows. If I want to switch to a native window, which I have not used since some minutes, I don't want to see all browser tabs as own windows.

Comment: It seems what you want is a [recent feature of Edge on MS Windows](https://www.wpxbox.com/how-to-enable-or-disable-alttab-between-tabs-in-microsoft-edge/) (I just came across it this week). Depending how important it is to you might want to try that, even if only to show if it works for your work flow.

Comment: @pbhj thank you for this hint. Maybe I will switch to windows on my next Laptop, since AFAIK WSL is quite good. This would be a drastic change. I use Linux on my device since 1996. Although I would like to stick to Linux. Is there no window manager which integrates  browser tabs?

Answer (score 1):

Despite not caring about implementation details they do matter, as they make the answer that you want impossible to give. Attempting to ignore that answer doesn't make it wrong. One tab per browser window is the only way to do this without a lot of effort to implement and maintain what you want.

The shortcut `Alt + Tab` switches between windows of open programs, and any browser window is one of those. Then the browser has its own internal window management system and accompanying keyboard shortcuts separate from those keybinds used for the OS. So, what you want is not possible without customization of at least the browser's internal window manager if not also that of the OS.

Better off just using the default keyboard shortcuts for the browser. Combined with the MRU sorting of the Quick Tabs extension you linked it would be slightly more effective than it already is.

- `Ctrl + Num` - Switch to tab 1-9 by number.
- `Ctrl + PgUp` - Switch one tab to the left.
- `Ctrl + PgDn` - Switch one tab to the right.
- `Ctrl + Shift + PgUp/PgDn` - Move current tab to the left or right, for organization.
- `Shift + Enter` - Open link in new window.

As a bonus, `Ctrl + PgUp/PgDn` also switches between tabs and `Ctrl + Shift + PgUp/PgDn` moves tabs around in some other programs that are running on top of Chromium, e.g. VSCode.

Comment: Ctrl+Tab changes browser tab, Alt+Tab changes application (and Meta+Tab changes desktops); as they want to differentiate between applications and browser tabs (see response to my comment) I can see no reason not to just use that. If you unified Alt+Tab, but want to be able to switch applications then you'd have to add a new shortcut for that.

Answer (score 0):

> Which window manager could help to get a simplified and unified application switching experience?

As others have already commented, there is windows and within windows there are tabs (at least in some of them). However most document browsers support to open new windows instead of new tabs and therefore any window manager known to me should suffice yours humble requirements.

So next time you open another document in a new tab, realize that this might fall below your own expectations and the action is counterproductive to your higher goals. Then strife for the better and stay in control of reaching your wanted achievements in being a productive (and educated) computer user that is able to master theirs own machine.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this work around. I would like to keep to use browser tabs. I am still looking for a solution

Comment: @guettli: IIRC Alphabets' Google has an operating system that's entirely a browser and therefore could perhaps already handle it that way or at least have an option for that. Maybe you want to give it a try, it is called ChromeOS and a quick search revealed there might be options to have it on your Ubuntu box: https://dottech.org/127959/how-to-install-chrome-os-ubuntu-linux-guide/

Comment: thank you for this hint. But I need some native applications like vscode, digikam.

Comment: @guettli: given the scenario with vscode, you want to alt-tab through all editors, diffs the commit dialog the extensions, tests, shells etc. I suppose? No idea about digikam, but perhaps similar. So which desktop environment is your preference? Gnome?